# HTML select dropdown arrow style

Tags: html, css, select

How to get the select dropdown arrow styled like shown in the image below.

```
<select>
    <option>Select Any</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: What you have tried yet ?

Comment: apply image as a background image on the select.

Comment: There's a trick in css with border. Take a look at this:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have mentioned you can hide the default select arrow by appearance property and apply your own style.

To support lower versions of IE(i haven't consider below 9) as appearance property won't work even with ms prefix , you can use the below method to have common support.

Arrow made by css not an image.

```js
$( "#sel_val" ).change(function() {
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $('#sel_txt').text(option);
});
```

```css
.wrapper{width:250px;margin:10px auto;}
.sbx{
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
 font-family:arial;
 position:relative; 
 background-color:#eee; 
}
.cus_selt:after{content:'';width:0; 
  height:0; 
  border-left:10px solid transparent;
  border-right:10px solid transparent;
  border-top:10px solid #FD025F;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1px;
  z-index:2;
  right:-6px;
transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.cus_selt{padding:20px;display:block;}
.styled {
float:left;
height: 56px;
margin: -58px 0 0;
opacity: 0;
width: 100%;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sbx" id="yoe_fld">
     <span class="cus_selt" id="sel_txt">Select a value*</span>
    <select id="sel_val" class="styled">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
        <option>option4</option>
        <option>option5</option>
        <option>option6</option>
        <option>option7</option>
      </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Source link for custom select dropdown [click](http://blog.idevelopweb.site/webideas/custom-select-dropdown/)

Source link for CSS arrow [click](http://blog.idevelopweb.site/webideas/arrow-using-css/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7hsxtubk/ Please check this.. When I use multiple select tags, it is not working as expected

Comment: @user3932810 You have used same class name for both dropdowns in the script, updated the code with unique id [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hsxtubk/3/)

Comment: Can't it be done generally using class name so that I don't have to write different ids for multiple tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="styled-select slate">
  <select>
    <option>Here is the first option</option>
    <option>The second option</option>
    <option>The third option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { margin: 20px; }

.styled-select {
   height: 29px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 240px;
}

.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 29px;
   padding: 5px; /* If you add too much padding here, the options won't show in IE */
   width: 268px;
}

.styled-select.slate {
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CVVr.png) no-repeat right center;
   height: 34px;
   width: 240px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this... Just set that image to Select's background.

```css
.select-style {
    width: 268px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 34px;
 position:relative;
 background:#fff;
}
.select-style>select{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    width:100%;
    background:none;
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:7px 10px;
}
.select-style>span{
  position:absolute;
   bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-right: 10px solid #ff0099;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ff0099;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
select::-ms-expand { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="select-style">
<select>
    <option>Select Any</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sank8893/bhy9do60/9/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in IE the default arrow is still visible

Comment: I am sorry I just observed that you have used entire image as background but I want this effect from pure css

Answer (score -1):

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/qu7wnj2f/)**

first you need to remove the default styling of the `select` dropdown. to do that use

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

for IE use :

```
select::-ms-expand { 
display: none;
}
```

then just apply your desired style, in this case with `background-image`

or you can use `border` to make a triangle and place it by using pseudo-elements like `:before` or `:after` .

```
select { 
    background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CVVr.png") no-repeat scroll right  bottom;
    background-size:contain;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in IE the default arrow is still visible

Comment: for IE use ` select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}`